# C++ makefile multiple headers one cpp

Tags: c++

I am having compiling errors. I have one cpp file and many headers. For the makefile I thought I needed to list all the headers file. The LinkedBinaryTree.h contains includes for all the other header files. This what I wrote:

```
 all: hw4a

 hw4a: LinkedBinaryTree.cpp linkedBinaryTree.h booster.h arrayQueue.  binaryTree.h        binaryTreeNode.h myExceptions.h queue.h
 g++ -o hw4a LinkedBinaryTree.cpp LinkedBinaryTree.h booster.h arrayQueue.h binaryTree.h     binaryTreeNode.h myExceptions.h queue.h 

clean:
rm hw4a
```

I was told that O just needed to do:

```
g++ LinkedBinaryTree.cpp -o bst.exe
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The latter is correct: `g++ -o result.exe source.cpp`. You must *not* include header files in the compiler command, since they are automatically included by the preprocessor already.

Of course the header files are still *dependencies* and must be listed in the makefile. That's why there is a special universal syntax to refer to the *first* reference only:

```
.phony: all clean

all: result.exe

result.exe: main.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $+

main.o: main.cpp class1.hpp lib2.hpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<
```

The `$+` means "all dependecies" (with repetition; `$^` also expands to all dependencies but uniquified), as you need for linking, while `$<` only means "first dependency", as you need for compiling.

While you're at it, sprinkle generous warning flags over your compiler commands.

Answer (score 0):

What you were told. Includes should be included, not being compiled as separate units.